# Why SessionFactory and ServiceRegistryBuilder are deprecated in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Why SessionFactory and ServiceRegistryBuilder are deprecated in hibernate and what are the benefits of newly introduced class StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found this.

Its basically a redesign, to improve sessionfactory creation process, instead of putting everything into Configuration object.

[redesign SessionFactory building link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2578)